# ion icon-displayed the icon twice instead one

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I added ion-icon to my code and it displayed twice.
This is my code:

`<span  item-right> <ion-icon name="create" [id]='create_icon' (click)="enableClick()" ></ion-icon></span>`

```css
on-icon {
    color: white !important;
    margin: 2px -13px -33px 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid #577995 !important;
    font-size: 27px;
    padding: 0px 7px 12px 0px;
   
 }
```

```html
 <ion-item [id]="'item-'+data.FieldName" padding>
           <ion-input 
            placeholder="insert your answer" 
           
           [id]="data.FieldName" 
           [type]="text" 
           name="data.FieldName" 
           class="search"></ion-input>
    <span  item-right>
    <ion-icon name="create" [id]='create_icon' (click)="enableClick()" ></ion-icon></span> 
    </ion-item>
```

[This is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvng.png)

this the inspect of the code:
[the inspect in f12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuywE.png)

I added style to hide it and it did not help

```css
    #shadow-root.icon-inner{
    display:none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    
}

:host svg{
    display:none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important; 
}
:host(.icon-inner){
    display:none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important; 
}
```

```html
<ion-icon name="create"   [id]="createIcon"  md="md-create"  ></ion-icon>
```

Comment: I think you'd better to give us more **html** and **style** codes for comprehending the issue.

Comment: I added, but most of the style come from ion libraries.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot reproduce the issue in despite of your adding.